# Get values from jscript datepicker in form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sqlparameter

I'm trying to use a `jscript Datepicker` UI calendar when I try to pass the text properties to an sqlparameter in `asp.net` .cs code. behind I can see the `cldStartProj` text box object but I can't see  the `cldEstProjEnd` or cldEndProj `textboxes`.

I am getting an error saying:

> "the name 'cldEstEndDate' does not exist in the current context"

How can I get the values from my `aspx` form from theses `datepicker` boxes?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#cldStartProj").datepicker();
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#cldEndProj").datepicker();
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#cldEstProjEnd").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<p><input type="datetime" id="cldStartProj"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" id="cldEstProjEnd"></p>
<p><input type="datetime" id="cldEndProj"></p>

cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjStartDate", cldStartProj.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjEstEndDate", cldEstProjEnd.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjEstEndDate", cldEndProj.Text);
```

Comment: Those are normal HTML textboxes, not ASP.Net Webform text boxes, that's your first problem.

Comment: you cannot access controls in asp.net like this. use server controls like <asp:textbox runat="server" id="cldStartProj" ></asp:textbox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asp:TextBox` for the datepicker. Then you can access it on the `.cs` code.

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="datePicker" ID="cldStartProj" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox CssClass="datePicker" ID="cldEstProjEnd" runat="server"  />
<asp:TextBox CssClass="datePicker" ID="cldEndProj" runat="server" />
```

Then in the script,

```
$(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker();
});
```

Use class for binding the datepicker. Id will be change after rendering as it has the attribute `runat=server`.

Answer (score 0):

they should asp controls to use in back-end like that

```
   <p> <asp:TextBox id="cldStartProj"  runat="server" /> </p>
    <p><p> <asp:TextBox id="cldEstProjEnd"  runat="server" /> </p>
    <p><p> <asp:TextBox id="cldEndProj"  runat="server" /> </p>

    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjStartDate", cldStartProj.Text);
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjEstEndDate", cldEstProjEnd.Text);
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjEstEndDate", cldEndProj.Text);
```